# Pig convert rows to columns

Tags: apache-pig

Following is the `dump` of the variable `data`.

```
(104)
(105)
(106)
(107)
(108)
(111)
(112)
(113)
(114)
(115)
(119)
(120)
```

How do I convert it to a `bag` of `tuples` as below (without `UDF` preferably):

```
{(104),(105),(106),(107),(108),(111),(112),(113),(114),(115),(119),(120)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP ALL` http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/basic.html#group

> Use ALL if you want all tuples to go to a single group; for example, when doing aggregates across entire relations.

```
A = LOAD '/tmp/data.txt' AS (n:int);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $1;
```